# Check if a response object returns no data

Tags: spring-boot, soap, spring-data-jpa, jax-ws

I have an endpoint that checks whether an identifier exists in the database and returns a status. A USSD API that will make a call to this endpoint.When i make a request with a nonexistent identifier (EcNumber) the response returns the message as i expect.However when i pass an identifier that is in the database im also getting the same status message.I need help in using either of isEmpty()/null to achieve the same:

ClientEndpoint.java

```
 @Endpoint
public class ClientEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.onewallet.org/webservices/disburse";
    @Autowired
    private IClientService clientService;   

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getClientByEcNumRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetClienttByEcNumResponse getClient(@RequestPayload GetClientByEcNumRequest request) {
        GetClienttByEcNumResponse response = new GetClienttByEcNumResponse();

    ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
    ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
    if ( clientInfo==null || clientInfo.getEcNumber()==null ){
        serviceStatus.setMessage("EC# not registered with MCP");
} else {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(clientService.getClientByEcNumber(request.getEcNumber() ), clientInfo);
        serviceStatus.setMessage("Welcome to MCP MobileLoans");
}
    response.setServiceStatus(serviceStatus);
    return response;
```

When i pass the request below for a valid EcNumber:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dis="http://www.onewallet.org/webservices/disburse">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dis:getClientByEcNumRequest>
         <dis:ecNumber>5501900T</dis:ecNumber>
      </dis:getClientByEcNumRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i am getting the response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:getClienttByEcNumResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.onewallet.org/webservices/disburse">
         <ns2:serviceStatus>
            <ns2:message>EC# not registered with MCP</ns2:message>
         </ns2:serviceStatus>
      </ns2:getClienttByEcNumResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I was passing the incorrect object for the check.Should have used **entity** instance instead of an instance of the **complexType** (from schema definition):

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getClientByEcNumRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetClienttByEcNumResponse getClient(@RequestPayload GetClientByEcNumRequest request) {
        GetClienttByEcNumResponse response = new GetClienttByEcNumResponse();

    ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
    **Client client=clientService.getClientByEcNumber(request.getEcNumber));**
    ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
    if ( client=null){
        serviceStatus.setMessage("EC# not registered with MCP");
} else {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(clientService.getClientByEcNumber(request.getEcNumber() ), clientInfo);
        serviceStatus.setMessage("Welcome to MCP MobileLoans");
}
    response.setServiceStatus(serviceStatus);
    response.setClientInfo(clientInfo)
    return response;
```